# Problem in interpreting the VECM model in Python

Tags: python, statistics, var

I have a data set with the name `allret_q2btc` with 3 variable columns goldret, equityret and btcret.
I have found the cointegration rank to be 3 and I tried running a VCEM model provided by the `statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm`, however, I am having trouble understanding the results.

```
VECM_res=VECM(allret_q2btc,k_ar_diff=1,coint_rank=3)
VECM_fit=VECM_res.fit()
VECM_fit.summary()
```

The following image gives the result of the above code. However, unlike R or Eviews, I couldn't understand the formatting of the result, I am having trouble interpreting the results. Please help me with this.

At the same time I want to know if someone has worked with the above package. If yes, please do tell me what use is VECMResult module in it. Appreciate if any example is attached.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVjMe.png)
[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EztU.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, keep in mind this equation used by statsmodel for VECM : Δyt=Πyt−1+Γ1Δyt−1+…+Γkar−1Δyt−kar+1+ut

What you see in the first 3 tables in image1 are the estimates of the kar−1 (=1 in this case) parameter matrices Γ1,…,Γkar−1 of the VECM(kar−1) model. you can get the exact coefficients using `VECM_fit.gamma`.

The other tables are about the estimates of alpha and beta. You can get those two neqsxcoint_rank (3x3 in this case) matrices directly using `VECM_fit.alpha` and `VECM_fit.beta`.

Note that : Π=αβ′ (Π=`VECM_fit.alpha.dot(VECM_fit.beta.T)`)

You can read more about the VECMResult attributes here : https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECMResults.html#statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.VECMResults

You can also get the VAR(2) representation of your VECM(1) model via `VECM_fit.var_rep`.

Finally, you can check that :

- `VECM_fit.var_rep[0]` = `VECM_fit.gamma + VECM_fit.alpha.dot(VECM_fit.beta.T) + np.diag(v=[1,1,1])`
- And `VECM_fit.var_rep[1]` = `-VECM_fit.gamma`